# Не работает AdMob после удачной работы

Tags: android, admob

И так, еще вчера все было хорошо, но уже сегодня приложения отказываеться показывать какую либо рекламу, то ли баннер, то ли тестовая, вообще казус.

Что я только не перепробовал, логи выдают это:

> 11-08 19:18:50.354 27594 28512 E Unity   :   at UnityEngine.MonoBehaviour.StartCoroutine (IEnumerator routine) [0x00013] in /Users/builduser/buildslave/unity/build/Runtime/Export/MonoBehaviour.bindings.cs:87
>   11-08 19:18:50.354 27594 28512 E Unity   :   at Main.OnAdFailToLoadedBanner (System.Object sender, System.EventArgs args) [0x0000f] in Q:\Unity\ThreeColorsSphere\Assets_Script\Main.cs:853
>   11-08 19:18:50.354 27594 28512 E Unity   :   at GoogleMobileAds.Api.BannerView.m__1 (System.Object sender, GoogleMobileAds.Api.AdFailedToLoadEventArgs args) [0x00015] in Q:\Unity\ThreeColorsSphere\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Api\BannerView.cs:127
>   11-08 19:18:50.354 27594 28512 E Unity   :   at GoogleMobileAds.Android.BannerClient.onAdFailedToLoad (System.String errorReason) [0x00024] in Q:\Unity\ThreeColorsSphere\Assets\GoogleMobileAds\Platforms\Android\BannerClie

и да, это я не криво скопировал, а лог такой, мне кажеться это все из-за этого сообщения [image], не понимаю каким боком Google Ads повлиял на AdMob но так уж случилось, и там после настройки аккаунта я ничего не добился, в чем может быть проблема?

Answer (score 1):

Закрыто. Проблема была в блокираторе рекламы на телефоне.